# How to intercept and remove a command line argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, command-line-arguments

After "upgrading" to Mavericks and Xcode 5, I have a variety of minor problems to deal with to make Xcode compile some of my older projects.

It appears that Xcode is passing a new argument to the `ld` linker, and there's really no stopping Xcode from doing so. An older version of `ld`, which I need for a variety of reasons, gives an error when seeing an argument it doesn't know (so my projects cannot compile).

What I need is a thin wrapper over my older version of `ld` to remove the "bad" arguments under certain circumstances. I thought that a bash shell script would be perfect, but bash is not my forte.

Here's what I've got:

```
# Look for conditions necessary to use older ld
... # (placeholder, obviously)

# Run older ld (pseudo condition)
if [ <old_ld_condition> ]; then
    ARGS=''
    for var in "$@"; do
        # Ignore known bad arguments
        if [ "$var" = '-dependency_info' ]; then
            continue
        fi

        ARGS="$ARGS $var"
    done

    /path/to/old/ld "$ARGS"
else
    /path/to/new/ld "$@"
fi
```

However, running `/path/to/old/ld "$ARGS"` results in `ld` interpreting the entire `$ARGS` string as one argument. Running `/path/to/old/ld $ARGS` results in `ld` receiving unescaped versions of previously escaped strings.

Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something about the nature of `$@`, how to manipulate it, and how to pass that manipulation to the older `ld`. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You can select the command-line toolset version from within Xcode, I do not know if that will help you or not? Generally unless you did a complete fresh install, the old SDKs and command-line toolset versions will coexist.

Comment: These projects are actual Xcode `.xcodeproj` files, and unfortunately I'm not in the position to bring them over to a command-line build process (e.g. `make`). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Run older ld (pseudo condition)
if [[ <old_ld_condition> ]]; then
    args=()
    for var; do
        # Ignore known bad arguments
        [[ $var != '-dependency_info' ]] && args+=("$var")
    done

    /path/to/old/ld "${args[@]}"
else
    /path/to/new/ld "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use Bash Arrays if you *really want* to stay with bash:

```
declare -a ARGS
for var in "$@"; do
    # Ignore known bad arguments
    if [ "$var" = '-dependency_info' ]; then
        continue
    fi
    ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}]="$var"
done
```

now `"${ARGS[@]}"` can be used just as `"$@"`. `man bash` for more information.